# How can I play local video files with react?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a website which allows users to play video files from anywhere on their system using React.

If I use the video  tag as:

```
<video className='myVideo' src="/home/tashif/Downloads/CSS/1.mp4" controls autoPlay> </video>
```

The video just won't load!

If I use  the tag as:

```
  <video className='myVideo' src={require("/home/tashif/Downloads/CSS/1.mp4")} controls autoPlay> </video>
```

I get the following error:

> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import
> /home/tashif/Downloads/CSS/1.mp4 which falls outside of the project
> src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
> You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from
> project's node_modules/.

I want to:

- Change the src prop, so, that should be a variable
- load video files from anywhere on the system and not be limited to a particular location

Is this possible with react? Or, should I switch back to Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround.

1. Create an express server to copy the local file from anywhere on the drive to the project's folder.

   fs.copyFileSync('from','to');
2. Use the **Video** tag as:

   <video src={require("location of the video after being copied/video.mp4")} controls autoplay>

Remember: Your video can be from anywhere, but, make sure to copy it to the same location and same name, video.mp4, as mentioned in the **require(...)** function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, put the video file inside your project public directory

for example for a video located in the folder /public/assets/video.mp4

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoPlay>
    <source src="/assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls autoPlay>
<source src={require("../rasimlar/video.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
```